# How to put selected checkboxes in a combobox in PowerApps?

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I want to put selected checkboxes in a combobox.
[image]

[image]

When these checkboxes are checked, they have to be showed and selected in the combobox.

Answer (score 1):

To do that you will need to define the `Items` property of the combo box with the same values that are shown in the combo boxes. In the example below, the Items property of the combo box is set to `[Checkbox1.Text, Checkbox2.Text, Checkbox3.Text, Checkbox4.Text]`. With that we can define the `DefaultSelectedItems` of the combo box to include only the selected checkboxes, and that will make the values show:

```
Filter(
    [
        If(Checkbox1.Value, Checkbox1.Text),
        If(Checkbox2.Value, Checkbox2.Text),
        If(Checkbox3.Value, Checkbox3.Text),
        If(Checkbox4.Value, Checkbox4.Text)
    ],
    Not IsBlank(Value)
)
```

Which will give the behavior seen below.

[image: Checkbox selection changes combo box selection]

Now, while this is possible to do, this only defines the default value of the combo box. The user could still open the combo box and choose different values - and they will not be reflected back in the check boxes. If that is not what you want, you can set the combo box DisplayMode property to DisplayMode.View (or DisplayMode.Disabled) - but in this case it will show up differently. If all you want is to display the selected values from the check boxes, you can use a label, and set its Text property to something similar to the expression below:

```
Concat(
    Filter(
        [
            If(Checkbox1.Value, Checkbox1.Text),
            If(Checkbox2.Value, Checkbox2.Text),
            If(Checkbox3.Value, Checkbox3.Text),
            If(Checkbox4.Value, Checkbox4.Text)
        ],
        Not IsBlank(Value)
    ),
    Value,
    ", "
)
```